# Pandas - How to groupby special partial string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv as the following:

```
Population  Region
1001        Rigolet (N.L.)
2000        Nain (N.L.)
3000        Lot 63 (P.E.I.)
4000        Lot 53 (P.E.I.)
5000        Burnt Islands (N.L.)
6000        Burgeo (N.L.)
7000        Ham-Nord (Que.)
8000        Chesterville (Que.)
1000        Warwick (Que.)
9000        Prince (Ont.)
1002        Wawa (Ont.)
```

I'd like to group by the ending part in the parentheses of the string in the *Region* column, such as '(N.L.)' or '(Ont.)'.

How could I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.str.rsplit` with `n=1` so you split on the first whitespace from the right. Then groupby on these values:

```
grps = df['Region'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[-1]
df.groupby(grps).#dosomething
```

When we wrint grps:

```
print(grps)
0       (N.L.)
1       (N.L.)
2     (P.E.I.)
3     (P.E.I.)
4       (N.L.)
5       (N.L.)
6       (Que.)
7       (Que.)
8       (Que.)
9       (Ont.)
10      (Ont.)
Name: Region, dtype: object
```